# Doc on how new runtimes can be added to CloudFoundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

I have tried following the steps for adding a new runtime to CF mentioned [here](http://programminggems.wordpress.com/2012/02/07/adding-a-runtime-and-framework-to-the-new-cloud-foundry/)

As James Foster himself mentioned in his post that CF is changing rapidly and the steps mentioned may not work for future releases. Yeah that is true. I just applied them to one of the latest releases and it did not work.

Any documentation that is relatively new?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed your question on vcap-dev at Google groups. This definitely the right place to be asking these kind of questions. This is a tricky one, as the platform is evolving so quickly. I think another good place to start would be to take a look at the source code.

The original patch for Elang is here;

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/vcap/pull/20/files

What runtime were you thinking about?

Dan